# Can't Save Snapshot to Data Model?

Tags: ios, model, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my viewController file, I initially had the following code:

```
    self.rootRef.child("users/").child("stringKey").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        self.userA.name     = snapshot.value!.objectForKey("name") as? String
        self.userA.urlOne   = snapshot.value!.objectForKey("urlOne") as? String
        self.userA.urlTwo   = snapshot.value!.objectForKey("urlTwo") as? String
    })

    print(self.userA.name)
    print(self.userA.urlOne)
    print(self.userA.urlTwo)
```

But for reasons unknown to me, the output is **empty**. When I put the print statements inside the observer event, I get the desired output. Why aren't I allowed to save the snapshot to a data model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[observeEventType] is processed in the background and your print commands are on the main thread. 
you need to do the saving in the background thread or use a method with a completion handler